# How do I replace a cell value with another cell value if the given conditions are met?

Tags: sql

I have a table 'Records' with 3 columns **'ID'**, **'date'** and **'name'**.

For example- 
If

```
id   date        name
----------------------
1    10/01/2019  Kate
1    10/01/2019  NULL
2    10/03/2019  Jake
3    10/03/2019  Sandy
2    10/03/2019  NULL
```

I am trying to come up with a generic code for matching and updating to make it look like-

```
id   date        name
----------------------
1    10/01/2019  Kate
1    10/01/2019  Kate
2    10/03/2019  Jake
3    10/03/2019  Sandy
2    10/03/2019  Jake
```

Comment: First you need an `UPDATE` statement, not `SELECT`. What if both names are not null?

Comment: @Serg : In this table, the second occurrence name is always Null

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan : I am trying to update the entire table and leave the matched rows as it is and only replace the name from Null to the previously occurring record name, which in this example is Kate.

Comment: as @Serg already mentioned *What if both names are not null?* ?? e.g. If there's another record with same ID = 1, date = 10/01/2019 and different name such as `Lucas` ? I mean if there are three records for ID 1 with two non-null names ..

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan : Each ID is unique to only 1 name

Comment: well, then you want to see duplicated rows.

Comment: @Nimmi . . . There is no "2nd" occurring name unless you have a column to specify the ordering.  Please clarify what you mean.  What if you have an ordering column and the first occurrence of `name` is `NULL`.  And -- for the record -- a table that has an `id` column with duplicates is quite misleading.

Answer (score 1):

With a self `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select
  r1.id, r1.date, coalesce(r1.name, r2.name)
from records r1 left join records r2
on r2.id = r1.id and r2.date = r1.date and r1.name is null and r2.name is not null
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xktbKE7wqgV4wG9Du1TeAi/0).
If you want to `UPDATE` the table then:

```
update records r1
set name = r2.name
from records r2             
where r1.id = r2.id and r1.date = r2.date
and r1.name is null and r2.name is not null;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xktbKE7wqgV4wG9Du1TeAi/2).
Results:

```
| id  | date                     | name  |
| --- | ------------------------ | ----- |
| 1   | 2019-10-01T00:00:00.000Z | Kate  |
| 2   | 2019-10-03T00:00:00.000Z | Jake  |
| 3   | 2019-10-03T00:00:00.000Z | Sandy |
| 1   | 2019-10-01T00:00:00.000Z | Kate  |
| 2   | 2019-10-03T00:00:00.000Z | Jake  |
```

Answer (score 0):

Update null name with the only possibly existing non-null.

```
UPDATE Records a1
SET name = (SELECT name 
            FROM  Records a2 
            WHERE (a1.id = a2.id) 
             AND date(a1.date)=date(a2.date)
             AND a2.name is NOT NULL)
WHERE a1.Name IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no "2nd occurring name" unless a column specifies the ordering.  Let me assume that you don't have such a column and merely want to fill in the `NULL` values.

I think a correlated subquery is the simplest approach:

```
update records r
    set name = (select r2.name
                from records r2
                where r2.id = r.id and r2.date = r.date and
                      r2.name is not null
                limit 1
               )
    where name is null;
```

Note the `limit 1`.  It seems possible that multiple rows could have a name on the same date.  This arbitrarily assigns one.  *It does not ensure that all have the same name.*

If you wanted that assurance, use a subquery:

```
update records r
    set name = r2.name
    from (select r2.date, r2.id, min(r2.name) as name
          from records r2
          group by r2.date, r2.id
         ) r2
    where r2.id = r.id and r2.date = r.date and
          r2.name is distinct from r.name;
```